# How to set all textboxes property shortcutsenabled to false

Tags: vb.net, textbox

i'm new in vb.net i want to validate textbox to disabled shortcuts.shortcutenabled.false is working with single one textbox ,i want to shortcutsenabled=false all my textbox in my form, anyone has idea? thank you in advance ! :D

I'm getting this error:

```
shortcutsenabled is not a member of system.windows.forms.control
```

My code:

```
For Each alltxtbox As Control In Me.Controls 
  If TypeOf alltxtbox Is TextBox Then 
     alltxtbox.ShortcutsEnabled = False 
  End If 
  Next
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply, here is my code:                                                                    



        For Each alltxtbox As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf alltxtbox Is TextBox Then
                alltxtbox.ShortcutsEnabled = False
                End If
      
        Next





the error is "shortcutsenabled is not a member of system.windows.forms.control"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
        If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            tb.ShortcutsEnabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Still not functioning , thank you for trying . Maybe i should disabled it one by one?

Comment: No error, but the disabling is not functioning. :(( help me please.

Comment: Please post whole code because this works fine when I test it.

Comment: For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls 
Dim tb As TextBox
    If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then 
       tb = CType(ctl, TextBox)
       tb.ShortcutsEnabled = False 
    End If   , this is your code that i already tried but not functioning i put it in form load but it still allows to right click on the textfield and copy or paste, should i import something?

Comment: I've edited my code. All textbox have property `ShortcutsEnabled = false` when form is loaded. You don't have to import. This should work.

Comment: I still have, still not working but if i try to use manual input like textbox1.shortcutsenabled=false is functioning.

Comment: Are you using windows forms? Asp.net textbox control?

Comment: I'm using windows form .

Comment: Well, than you're doing something wrong but I can't help you cause you didn't post your whole code, just this each loop.

Comment: I don't have another codes that might affect to the shortcutsenabled codes, btw thank you for your help :) . God bless.

Comment: Dude, i got the problem, btw my textbox is in the panel. i tried to place it in the window then wola it function well, but i want this in the panel, what should i do? :DD